# Get Exact timestamp value?

Tags: sql, oracle, timestamp

I am trying to subtract some days from 'current_timestamp' and converting that to timestamp using to_timestamp() function in Oracle. But I am always getting start of day time, that is 12 AM.

When I execute

```
select to_timestamp(current_timestamp - 3) from dual;
```

It will give me result like,

> 18-FEB-14 12.00.00.000000000 AM

But I need exact deduction of 3 days from current time.

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 3):

```
select current_timestamp - 3 ts from dual;
```

or

```
SELECT SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '3' DAY AS day FROM dual;
```

Comment: The first one strips the time part, but the second one works.

Answer (score 2):

Will give you time as well:

```
select sysdate - 3 from dual;
```

Edit based on your comment:

```
select to_timestamp(to_char(sysdate-3,'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS'),'DD-Mon-RR HH24:MI:SS') from dual;
```

Or more simply:

```
select systimestamp - 3 from dual
```

Comment: I need timestamp also , So when I use to_timestamp() function it gave me the same result :(

Comment: With to_char(0 it worked.. Thanks!!. One  more doubt is When I tried option '3/24'(3 hours) instead '3'(3 Days).. Then it's taking some other timings and deducting 3 hours.. Any Idea?

Answer (score 2):

An important difference is that SYSDATE gives you server time, and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP gives you session time.

Also, according to the documentation, TO_TIMESTAMP operates on CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, or NVARCHAR2 data types, not DATE. So I think you need to look elsewhere:

```
    SELECT CAST (SYSDATE AS TIMESTAMP) from dual;
```